# Can we access request header on Firebase Auth triggers i.e onCreate?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

How can one access the IP and country in firebase auth onCreate trigger? Is there any other way to get this info?

For the front end, I'm using firebase-ui and for user register using the following method.

```
app.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
```

Cloud Functions code:

```
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { 
     clientIp: 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx', // required here headers['x-forwarded-for'] 
     country: 'countryName'  // required here headers['x-appengine-country']
  })
  .then(() => {
    
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Function is triggered by the Google/Firebase infrastructure, and thus the headers are the values from that infrastructure. No information about the user/device that called `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is available beyond what is passed in the `user` object.

If you need more information, consider implementing a callable function that you call directly from your code passing both the credentials (that you now pass to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`) and the additional information you need, and then creating the user in the Cloud Functions code itself.